# Stored Procedure returns multiple tables but EF only creates single resultset with the only First datatable result

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have SP `SPGetEmployeeDetails` which returns two `datatables` like

```
select * from employee
select * from employeecompletedtraining
```

And I included the SP in the EF edmx. It creates result set which only returns the properties of first `datatable` i.e (select * from employee).
But, I want both result sets using EF.
We can easily achieve in using ADO connection which gives both results in `dataset`. I want to achieve using EF database first approach.

Any assistance will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same requirement and was able to solve the by changing the function Import section in ef xml. Initially there is only **one set of return type**, you need to override the return type of the function import which will return **two sets of record type**.

Please go through the link below:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram